# Objective C global constants with case/switch

Tags: objective-c, ios, constants, switch-statement

Is there any way to use global int constants in Objective C that work in a case/switch statement?  The technique here (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/538996/constants-in-objective-c) lets me access the constants everywhere, but does not let me put them into a switch statement.

in .h

```
FOUNDATION_EXPORT const int UNIT_IDLE;
FOUNDATION_EXPORT const int UNIT_DEFEND;
```

in .m

```
int const UNIT_IDLE = 0;
int const UNIT_DEFEND = 1;
```

Error is "Expression is not an integer constant expression"

Comment: what does your `switch` look like?

Comment: possible duplicate of [integer constant does 'not reduce to an integer'](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/554419/integer-constant-does-not-reduce-to-an-integer)

Comment: I saw that solution, and I'm pretty new so I probably just don't understand, but I don't know how to access my enum in Object 1 in Object2.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why can I not use my constant in the switch - case statement in Objective-C ? \[error = Expression is not an integer constant expression\]](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6585276/why-can-i-not-use-my-constant-in-the-switch-case-statement-in-objective-c-e)

Comment: Use `const static` instead.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I usually use enumerations with typedef statements when using constants which I will use in a switch statement.

For example, this would be in a shared .h file such as ProjectEnums.h:

```
enum my_custom_unit
{
    MyCustomUnitIdle    = 1,
    MyCustomUnitDefend  = 2
};
typedef enum my_custom_unit MyCustomUnit;
```

I can then use code similar to the following switch statement in my .c, .m, .cpp files:

```
#import "ProjectEnums.h"

- (void) useUnit:(MyCustomUnit)unit
{
    switch(unit)
    {
        case MyCustomUnitIdle:
        /* do something */
        break;

        case MyCustomUnitDefend:
        /* do something else */
        break;

        default:
        /* do some default thing for unknown unit */
        break;
    };
    return;
};
```

This also allows the compiler to verify the data being passed to the method and used within the switch statement at compile time.

Comment: I'm a bit dense, but from another object can I have access to enum my_custom_unit?  Or do I have to copy-paste the enum?  I want to the constants shared.

Comment: @Andrew You can declare the enums in a shared header file.  I typically create a file called something like ProjectEnumerations.h which is included by any of the source files which will use the enums. I've updated my examples to demonstrate.

Comment: Thanks so much! I was missing that last piece of how to share the enums.

Answer (score 1):

I think your best option is using `enum types`. Just declare a type in your header file and then you are ready to use it in a switch statement.

**class.h**

```
typedef enum{
    kEditGameModeNewGame = 0,
    kEditGameModeEdit = 1
}eEditGameMode;
```

**class.m**

```
eEditGameMode mode = kEditGameModeEdit;

switch (mode) {
    case kEditGameModeEdit:
        // ...
        break;
    case kEditGameModeNewGame:
        // ...
        break;

    default:
        break;
}
```

Good luck!

Comment: Is there any way to share the enum between different objects? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

[Official guideline](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CodingGuidelines/Articles/NamingIvarsAndTypes.html) says you should use "enumerations for groups of related constants that have integer values." That may solve your problem and improve code.