# Error in using constant in the switch-case statement

Tags: objective-c, switch-statement, constants

**PRECAP:** I have followed [Why can I not use my constant in the switch - case statement in Objective-C ?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6585276/why-can-i-not-use-my-constant-in-the-switch-case-statement-in-objective-c-e) but still the problem persists. Also I am not allowed to comment my question in the above link and that is why I put this question again.

In a iOS app, I have **constants.h** as:

```
int const Category_Default = 1;
```

In another file (say **test.m**) I used it in this way:

```
switch(//someVariable) {
    case Category_Default:
        //do something
    default:
        //do something
}
```

Unfortunately the compiler gives me an error as **Case label does not reduce to an integer constant**.

I am aware that the value of a constant must be known at compile time to be able to be used in a `case` within a `switch`.

I even initialized the constant in the .h file itself as suggested in [Why can I not use my constant in the switch - case statement in Objective-C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6585276/why-can-i-not-use-my-constant-in-the-switch-case-statement-in-objective-c-e) but still the error persists.

**NOTE**: I don't want to use `#define` or `enum` in this case.

Any help on this would be much appreciated.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why can I not use my constant in the switch - case statement in Objective-C ? \[error = Expression is not an integer constant expression\]](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6585276/why-can-i-not-use-my-constant-in-the-switch-case-statement-in-objective-c-e)

Comment: @Shai Yes it is a duplicate but I already mentioned that I followed it and yet the problem persists!!

Answer (score 0):

It's Compiler rule my friend. You need to use enum or #define instead.

case labels can change when they are variable as per compiler
the compiler considers a switch statement as a set of gotos. that's why it can't be variables

Comment: Sorry but I already mentioned that this option of using `enum` or `#define` isn't valid on my case as I am not authorised to change the `constants.h` file

Comment: In that case you use an if / else statement.